# Other Sibling Avengers?

Tags: marvel, avengers

Joss Whedon spoke on *The Avengers 2* to [Yahoo](http://movies.yahoo.com/video/joss-whedon-talks-avengers-2-020841970.html), and said:

> I've got these two characters, y'know.  I've got two of my favorite characters from the comic books, a brother/sister act.  They're in the movie.

Most news sites are reporting this as confirmation that Quicksilver and Scarlet Witch are in *Avengers 2*, but all Joss says is that they're a brother and sister team.  It's been [previously-established](http://www.superherohype.com/features/articles/170425-exclusive-interview-with-marvel-studios-prez-kevin-feige) that Marvel and Fox both have rights to them, so it is possible that he is referring to Quicksilver and Scarlet Witch.  But he also didn't name them specifically, and there have been quite a few Avengers over the years.

Are there other brother/sister Avengers besides Quicksilver and Scarlet Witch?

Comment: If both Marvel and Fox own them that extends to the X-Men universe which could mean they could potentialy bring in Northstar and Aurora even though they've never to my knowledge been Avengers.

Comment: @Monty129 Read the second link, there's a special deal in place for those 2 specific characters, it's not a loophole that would let Marvel use whatever X-universe/mutant characters they want.

Comment: Ah I was just trying to remember any sibling heroes from Marvel and Fox instantly made me think X-Men.

Comment: Maybe a Fantastic Four cameo?? Susan and Johnny Storm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There has only been one true pair of siblings on the Avengers and that is the Scarlet Witch and Quicksilver, two mutants who are the offspring of the mutant mastermind, Magneto. [The Scarlet Witch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarlet_Witch) (Wanda Maximoff) and [Quicksilver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksilver_%28comics%29) became an Avenger in Avengers #16 (May 1965).

Two other sibling pairs might also qualify:

- Wonder Man and the Vision who shared a psychological structure. The Vision's mind was once based on Wonder Man's mental engrams.
- The Vision and Jocasta (granted a provisional Avenger) were both created by Ultron, technically rendering them "siblings".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In a technicality, Daken and Laura Howlett are adopted siblings, and Daken has been part of the Avengers, even if it was the Dark Avengers. But I highly doubt that they'd use the pair of them, because Laura is too new of a character, and she's only an adopted child of Wolverine, and also because Daken would be too much of a troublemaker.

Comment: ...and also because using Daken when you can't have Wolverine seems a little unlikely.  I think you're right!

Comment: Also: Hello April, welcome to the site.  When you have a chance, please take a second to [read the FAQ](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq).  I hope you enjoy your stay.